# Does ejb stateless class has to be public?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

Can @Stateless class have different modifiers than public? In documentation I have only found constraints of constructor/methods visibility, but nothing interesting about class level access.

Comment: Well, documentation has a lack of this information, but i know it works as default too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to ejb3-1 [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/):

> 4.9.2 Session Bean Class
>
> The following are the requirements for the session bean class:
>
> • The class must be defined as public, must not be final, and must not be abstract. The
> class must be a top level class

Comment: That actually contradicts a little bit with information from @Bruno Frano

Comment: no, it doesn't:  "works as default too" just means it works now (on some containers) but is not guaranteed to work in future.